# How to delete node in linked list by value even if there is only one node left in the list

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a delete node by the specified value. And it works until there is only one node left but i want to be able to delete the nodes even if it will cause the list to be empty. However i keep getting segmentation fault. Please help me solve the problem>< I have looked at other similar questions but none of them have the problem of deleting the final node, leaving an empty list.

```
void remove_first(sllist *ptr_sll, int value) {
  node* head = ptr_sll->head;
  node* del = find(ptr_sll,value);
  if(head == del)  
  {  
    if(head->next == NULL)  
    {  
       delete head;
    } 
    else{
      /* Copy the data of next node to head */
      head->value = head->next->value;  

      // store address of next node  
      del = head->next;  

      // Remove the link of next node  
      head->next = head->next->next;  

      // free memory  
      delete del;  
    }
   
  }
  else{
    // find the previous node  
  node *prev = head;  
  while(prev->next != NULL && prev->next != del)  
    prev = prev->next;  

  if(prev->next == NULL)  
  {  
    return;  
  }  
  // Remove node from Linked List  
  prev->next = prev->next->next;  

  // Free memory  
  delete del;  
  }
}
```

Edit: sorry the segment fault was from different codes i tested earlier. For this chunk of codes its double free or corruption error

Comment: I got a mental seg. fault when I read "delete node by value." I think you just mean "delete node [normally]."

Comment: @Elliott the way this function works is find the node by value and deleting the node

Comment: See the `del_node()` function in [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much! this has helped to solve my problem!:)

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes it just helps to see it done. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) for further explanation on using both the *address-of-the-node* and a *pointer-to-node* to iterate. Makes things very easy once you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign head = NULL if head == del and head->next == NULL

Comment: i tried that in the if(head->next == NULL) and i get "double free or corruption (fasttop)" error

Comment: For that make sure you don't leave a pointer in the list that still points to a node that you deleted. Also if this is c++ and you have a class make sure your class does not violate the rule of 3 / 5 /0

Comment: @SoulessNight, this isn't a paid debugging service. Jugal has pointed out two definite bugs in your code. The fact that it doesn't solve your problem simply shows that you didn't do enough prep. work for this question.

Comment: @Elliott I am not asking anyone to debug? I am simply saying that i have tried setting the head to null already and it didnt fix the problem.So im asking if there is an alternative way and i have already tried to Google alot on how to solve these errors but did not find any that matches what i needed which is why i came to ask on this forum

Comment: @drescherjm i have tried it earlier before i posted and it didnt work which was why i removed it for the post. And i have tried it again after Jungal posted his answer but i got the same error